# Number of small herbivores per acre

Tags: ecology

I am interested in world building of a alien biospheres, as is done for example in [Alien Biospheres](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6xPxnYMQpquNuaEffJzjGjMsr6VktCYl) series. In this context, I would like to know some rule of thumb how to estimate number of animals living on certain area. I found a great resource to answer the question on the [world-builders.org](http://www.world-builders.org/lessons/less/biomes/SunEnergy_good.html) pages. Their recipe is the following:

1. Different biomes produce different number of kilocalories per year per $\mathrm{m}^2$ in plant production. For rain forrest, we get 9000 kcal / year / $\mathrm{m}^2$, while for example for savanna, we get approximately 3000 kcal / year / $\mathrm{m}^2$.
2. Only 10% of this production is transferred to Tier 1 consumers (herbivores). So if there is 3000 kcal / year / $\mathrm{m}^2$ produced in plants in savanna, there should be 300 kcal / year / $\mathrm{m}^2$ produced in bodies of herbivores.
3. Only 10% of this production is transferred into bodies of Tier 2 consumers (carnivores eating Tier 1 consumers). We can continue in the same way into higher tiers.

What I like about this rule is that is allows answering question like: "What will be average number of bisons in certain area?" and similar. As a cross-check, I tried to calculate maximal number of cows that can live on certain area of a pasture. The pasture is similar to savanna and we therefore can expect approximately 300 kcal / year / $\mathrm{m}^2$ in bodies of cows. Since meat has caloric density cca 3000 kcal / kg and since a cow weighs approximately 700 kg, we get cca **0.6 cow per acre per year**. So far, the rule works very well.

However it fails horribly, when applied fir example to number of rodents on the fields. By the same calculation, with mouse mass estimated to 27 g, I am getting cca 15 000 mice per acre per year. Even for bigger rodents (270 g), I am getting 1500 rodents, which is way too much. The real mice density is somewhere between [15 mice per acre](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Rodent-density-estimates-D-as-rodents-per-hectare-1-SE-by-species-together-with_tbl5_237725934) and 50 mice per acre. Of course, unlike with the cows, the rodents do not consume all the fields production, but is still seems like a significant over-estimate, since they would need to eat only 0.1% - 1% if the whole production.

My question is: **Why does the model fail for small herbivores and is there a better model which I could use?**

Comment: Before you as, I am asking here and not in Biology stack exchange, because I am looking for a simple rule of thumb for world-building. The real thing will have many exceptions, depend a lot on group of animals, etc.

Comment: you could improve this a lot by showing us your original calculations, so we can see where the error is. my guess would be it would be failing to account for how much more efficient large animals are, a rodent needs to eat more than its body weight a day. if it is supporting 700lbs of cow it should be supporting drastically smaller mass of rodents.

Comment: @alex but it should not be possible to get a larger mass of mice than cow on a given output, cows are drastically more efficient per pound than mice.

Comment: Link to the calculation is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16kJRXNJcNBFB-aO-63uqZNKobKH8iwNtTR06yYhr6qY/edit?usp=sharing

The numbers for cows and mice are per hectar, not acre. The two numbers listed here are highlighted in green.

Comment: (1) The smaller the animal, the faster the metabolism. Mice need to eat their body weight of food per day. (2) Those 50 mice per acre are *in competition* with the cows, aren't they? Have you seen a statistic of mice per square furlough *in the absence of competition*, and, equally importantly, *in the absence of predation*? Remembering my grandfather's granary, I can assure you that given an abudant source of food you can have very high concentrations of mice. (3) You may want to clarify what you mean when you say that a pasture is similar to a savannah. In my mind they are quite different.

Comment: @AlexP: I think they are in competition with anything that normally lives on the fields, +they are being hunted. You are right that without any competition, the numbers would be much higher. But how to put it into the model?

Comment: @John: That's the point. The smaller the animal, the faster the metabolism. Mice need to eat their body weight of food per day, just to stay alive. Gaining weight is much more difficult for a small animal than for a large animal.

Comment: This may help, a pound of mouse requires about 10 times as many calories a cow. https://www.pnas.org/content/100/7/4046  and on top of that a a cow os much more efficent at extracting those calories from the food it eats. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3812987/

Comment: Regarding similar to savanna: From biomes they state at world-builders.org (temperate forest, rain forest, savanna), I took savana as the closest, because large portion of its production is grass. But you are right that the pasture / field production can differ from the 3000 kca./year/sq meter.

Comment: Regarding the efficiency of metabolism: I think you have a good point. I tried to calculate that as well using the [Kleiber's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber%27s_law). Then the number of mice are smaller, yet probably still too high.

Comment: Regarding the predation / competition: This may well be the answer. But then I wonder how to include the predation and competition into the model?

Comment: I have a perfect source for you but it is also behind a very steep pay wall, https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Metabolic+Ecology%3A+A+Scaling+Approach-p-9780470671535 don't reinvent the wheel, if you search the term "Metabolic Ecology" you can find a lot of material on calculation.

Comment: Don't forget that "herbivores" is bigger than just mammals - it also includes insects. Mice are competing with far-more-numerous insects for many of the same foods. And many of those insects get eaten by other tiny voracious predators (hello, spiders and mites!) in a rich foodweb before the predator size grows large enough to be noticeable (like small birds) to most folks.

Answer (score 3):

The comments on your question do a good job of framing the issues with your approach for smaller animals. There are three ways you can look at this question.

**1. Back of the envelope math**

This is your current approach. This can give you rough numbers that should act as a sanity check. You're using the caloric content of an animal, which is closely related to its mass. In a [study of forest mammals](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/284596), body mass accounted for more than half of a species' population density. But that still leaves a lot of room for error. To get more accurate, you can look for studies into the total biomass supported by different environments, e.g. [Equatorial Rain Forest](https://www.jstor.org/stable/5128?seq=1).

**2. Species-specific calorie estimates**

If you want to get more specific, look at the actual data for different species. If you're creating a new species in your alien world, you can base them on Earth species. For example, there has been research into [mice](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK231918/), [pigs](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/myQeL_v_i7sC?hl=en), [poultry](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/bbV1FUqRcM0C?hl=en), [small ruminants](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/1FZOX5oQ7MUC?hl=en), and other animals.

**3. Count the number of animals in different contexts**

If you want the most accurate estimates, you can look at how many of a given species actually live in different types of environments. This is the least flexible approach, since slight changes in the animal or environment could result in very different numbers. There have been population counts of wild [rats](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3669272?seq=1) and other animals.